# Got the an intermediate value in the last chained Option.bind?

Tags: f#

I have the following code

```
let getHtml location = 
    let request (url:string) = 
        let response = httpRequest (getFullUri url)
        response.Headers.TryFind "Location"

    request location  
    |> Option.bind (fun x -> request x) 
    |> Option.bind (fun x -> request x) // need the return of httpRequest inside request
```

I want the code return the last call of `httpRequest`. Not the return of `request`.

---

Update: tried the following code. Error on the last `snd`. I think I can use a mutable variable to implement it. But is it F# idiomatic?

```
let getHtml location = 
    let request (url:string) = 
        let response = httpRequest (getFullUri url)
        match response.Headers.TryFind "Location" with 
        | Some location -> Some location, response
        | None -> None, response

    request location |> fst
    |> Option.bind (fun x -> request x |> fst) 
    |> Option.bind (fun x -> request x |> snd) // Error on snd
```

---

Use mutable variable?

```
let getHtml location = 
    let mutable resp : FSharp.Data.HttpResponse = ???
    let request (url:string) = 
        let response = httpRequest (getFullUri url)
        resp <- response
        response.Headers.TryFind "Location"

    request location 
    |> Option.bind (fun x -> request x) 
    |> Option.bind (fun x -> request x)

    if not (resp = null) then Some resp else None
```

Comment: This seems pretty obvious. What have you tried? Where are you stumped?

Comment: I've updated the question. Can you post an answer?

Comment: The `match` expression in your update seems completely unnecessary. You could just do `let locationOpt = response.Headers.TryFind "Location"` and then the return value is `locationOpt, response`. Also, you mention an error on the `snd` call on the last line, but when I tried to duplicate your issue I got no error, so it's hard to tell what the problem is. Could you let us know *what error you got* on that `snd` call?

Comment: @rmunn The function `httpRequest` doesn't return `string` but `HttpResponse`.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - If that's the error that you got, then that means that you're expecting `getHtml` to return a string, right? But the code you wrote using `snd` returns an HttpResponse. So you would have the same problem with the mutable version of your code. What you really need to do is after the `snd` call, get the content of the HttpResponse and return that.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - In other words, you're confused about what you're *actually trying to do*. Your initial problem statement was that you want your `getHtml` function to "return the last call of `httpRequest`", and that would be an `HttpResponse` object. But if you're getting an error message that you expected a string but got an HttpResponse instead, then your initial problem statement in the question wasn't actually what you needed. What you actually needed was not the result of the last `httpRequest` call, but *the string content* from that HttpResponse object. Different thing entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think want you want to do is actually make `getHtml` recursive, so that when an HTTP request returns a 201 or a 300-level response code, you follow the `Location` header to the redirected page and return the correct HTML.  You could do that with a simple pattern match on the `response.StatusCode` and the location header, as follows:

```
open FSharp.Data

// stub
let getFullUri (url: string) = 
    sprintf "%A" <| System.UriBuilder(url)

// stub
let httpRequest = Http.Request

// fetches the requested URL, following redirects as necessary
let rec getHtml location = 
    let response = httpRequest (getFullUri location)
    match response.StatusCode, response.Headers |> Map.tryFind "Location" with
    | (status, Some redirectUrl) when status = 201 || (status >= 300 && status < 400) -> 
        getHtml redirectUrl
    | _ -> 
        response
```

Is that what you were going for?  I tested it with the following URL that returns a 302, and it got the HTML for the page to which it was redirected:  https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/302.html